# Exceptions in Python and their specific extensions

Tags: python-2.7

I have a question regarding the extension of the use of the 'try' and 'except' function in Python.

So, lets say I have this body of code for ValueErrors:

```
try:
    option = raw_input("Enter '1' to create a render of the Julia fractal or '2' for the  Mandelbrot fractal")

except ValueError:
    print ("Please enter a number only!")
```

This is very useful of course, but is this function extendable to specific cases where the creator such as I only want them to either put in 1 or 2 and nothing else? Looking for some guidance for this!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can raise a `ValueError` yourself if the user-supplied values don't match your specifications:

```
try:
    option = raw_input("Enter '1' to create a render of the Julia fractal or '2' for the  Mandelbrot fractal")
    if option not in ['1', '2']:
       raise ValueError("Value wasn't 1 or 2")
except ValueError:
    print ("Please enter 1 or 2 only!")
```

You could also create a custom exception type if you want to handle that particular exception differently from others:

```
class IllegalNumberError(Exception):
   pass

try:
    option = raw_input("Enter '1' to create a render of the Julia fractal or '2' for the  Mandelbrot fractal")
    if option not in ['1', '2']:
       raise IllegalNumberError("Value wasn't 1 or 2")
except IllegalNumberError:
    print("Please enter 1 or 2 only!")
except Exception as e:
    print("Unexpected exception occured: %s" % e)
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I was thinking it was some complicated body of code, but you made it look so simple. I almost thought I was reading pseudocode for a second.

Comment: Right, earlier it said to wait 7mins, so I went to do finish up my python code and lost track of time.